# What is the term for a code that has duplicate or redundant/equivalent symbols?

Tags: communication, encoder, signal-theory

I'm having a hard time performing a literature search because I can't find the right search terms.

I'm looking for what you name a code over some alphabet that treats multiple symbols equivalently.  E.g. if the alphabet is `{A, B, C, D}` the code interprets `A` and `B` as equivalent and `C` and `D` as equivalent when decoding a code word.

I understand this is rarely if ever actually done (you can always just half your alphabet size and space your symbols out more if you're goal is minimizing errors,) but I'm looking for examples where it has been done, perhaps where the symbol `A` or `B` is chosen to satisfy some (possibly time varying) spectral requirements, or some other special requirements of the transmission line.

Comment: maybeb`fuzzy logic`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the specific use case of balancing out a DC bias on a signal, this is referred to as a [paired-disparity code](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paired_disparity_code&useskin=vector). Such a code chooses between synonymous codewords in order to keep the average voltage on the line zero, usually so that it can be transformer-coupled¹.

Perhaps the most common paired-disparity code is 8b/10b encoding, used in a wide variety of signalling protocols including (but not limited to) such common ones as gigabit ethernet, some versions of PCIe, DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort, USB 3.x, and SATA.

---

¹While an ideal transformer (with finite winding resistance so you don't get infinite current) would be capable of handling an arbitrary DC bias on the signal (it would just lead to some wasted energy from the increased current), a real one would not. The DC component of the current in a real transformer will cause it to saturate, which will prevent good input-to-output coupling; the signal level on the output of the transformer will drop significantly, to levels far below that needed by the receiver. And it will waste energy from both the increased current *and* the hysteresis of the transformer core.